# Working with dynamic and static sections together in a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am having some problem to manage my cells in a tableview.

I have one table view with two sections:
The first one, I have 3 custom cells, with static cells.

The second one, I have a dynamic type.

To work with the dynamic one, no problem is occurring, but the static, I don't know how to "reuse" them.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexpath.section = 0){
        //here is the question, how to return the stactis that had already been defined
    }else{
        return cell //here is okay, i can return the dynamic
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
     if(indexpath.section = 0){
         //here is the question, how to return the stactis that had already been defined
         static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StaticCell";

         StaticCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         return cell;


     }else{

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DynamicCell";

         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         if(cell == nil){
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
         }
         return cell;
     }
```

Comment: so each of the 3 static cells, i need to put an indentifier? the dynamic one i made different but works correctly